# When will EOS Storage be available? What alternatives can be used until then?

Tags: storage

I hear that EOS Storage will not be available on mainnet launch. Let's suppose a developer is building a media-intensive dapp like Instagram. Where do you suggest she stores her images and videos in the absence of EOS Storage on EOSIO launch? And when is EOS Storage expected to be available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know when the storage will be available, but it will be IPFS. So to keep a similar and also decentralized structure, I'm already integrating IPFS in my dApps and storing only the file hash in the chain. That's also what Everipedia is doing. I believe doing this way when EOS BP's starting to serve IPFS it will be a hassle free transition for dApps.

Comment: The aims of the smart contract is to provide easy access to the file hash on IPFS

Answer (score 1):

Right now, BlockOne's suggested solution for this is [using Demux](https://medium.com/eosio/introducing-demux-deterministic-databases-off-chain-verified-by-the-eosio-blockchain-bd860c49b017):

> Demux solves these problems by off-loading storage and queries to your
>   preferred database (MongoDB, Postgres etc). As blockchain events
>   happen, your chosen database is updated by Updater functions, which
>   deterministically process an array of Action objects. The database can
>   then be queried by your front-end DAPP through a suitable API (for
>   example, REST or GraphQL), reducing the amount of direct interaction
>   with the blockchain in order to retrieve data for your application.
>   This also can help developers to limit the amount of data that needs
>   to be stored in RAM, lowering applications’ operating costs whilst
>   also improving their architectural efficiency.

[image]